# I can't get all metadata tags in Python with Pillow

Tags: python, image, tags, python-imaging-library, metadata

I'm trying to get all metadata tags from an image using the Pillow library but I get only 5 tags here :

```
ExifOffset          :140
Make                :HUAWEI
Model               :VOG-L29
Software            :Adobe Lightroom 5.0 (Android)
DateTime            :2019:12:10 11:40:30
```

This is my code :

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS


file = 'IMG_20191210_114027.jpg'
img = Image.open(file)

img_exif = img.getexif()

for tag_id in img_exif:
    tag=TAGS.get(tag_id,tag_id)
    data=img_exif.get(tag_id)
    if isinstance(data,bytes):
        data=data.decode()
    print(f"{tag:20}:{data}")
```

and this is the pic I was using [IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IIX85hwlla1PsFKi8Y_xUIOVRQNV4pNc/view?usp=sharing)

If we check this [WEBSITE](http://metapicz.com/#landing) we get more tags like:

```
Make                    HUAWEI
Model                   VOG-L29
Software                Adobe Lightroom 5.0 (Android)
ModifyDate              2019:12:10 11:40:30
ExposureTime            1/6900
FNumber                 1.6
ExposureProgram         Program AE
DateTimeOriginal        2019:12:10 11:40:30
ShutterSpeedValue       1/6900
ApertureValue           1.6
BrightnessValue         0
ExposureCompensation    0
MaxApertureValue        1.6
MeteringMode            Multi-segment
LightSource             Daylight
Flash                   No Flash
FocalLength             5.6 mm
SubSecTime              758
SubSecTimeOriginal      758
FocalLengthIn35mmFormat 55 mm
LensModel               HUAWEI P30 Pro Rear Main Camera
```

How can I get all tags like on **metapicz** website?
And how can I store each tag in different variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code exactly with the latest version of Pillow (Pillow==8.4.0) and got the same incomplete result. Then I downgraded to the version 7.0.0 and it worked!

`pip install pillow==7.0.0 --upgrade`

Comment: Well thanks it's worked on version 8.0.0 but I still don't get (ISO Speed) , And please how can I store each tag in different variable?

Comment: You can create a dictionary outside the loop and set each tag: data to it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

imagename = "abc.jpg"
image = Image.open(imagename)

exifdata = image.getexif()

for tag_id in exifdata:
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    print(f"{tag:25}: {data}")
```

I run those code on Google collab and gave me those result[image: Result image]